# Iterating through requests until return is none (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, httpx

I am working with ticket inventory for various events that have an unknown total number of listings.  For each listing, I get a return of some data such as price, quantity, owning user, etc.  To collect this data I have created an async script that sends a number of requests to fetch data (1 request per each listing).  However, I am using the range function in a for loop and overestimating the number of listings there are to get all of the data.

This returns data fine, however I need to find a way to send the exact number of requests *or* stop collecting data once requests begin to return none to make this more efficient and more applicable to a larger number of different events.

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
payload_variables = [
        "filter_ticket_id=&filter_tmr_ticket_id=&filter_ticket_ext_id=&filter_vendor_id=&filter_ticket_section=&filter_ticket_row=&filter_ticket_seat=&filter_ticket_last_change_from=&filter_ticket_last_change_to=&filter_price_from=&filter_price_to=&filter_cost_from=&filter_cost_to=&filter_qty_from=&filter_qty_to=&filter_tag_id=&filter_consignment=0&filter_non_consignment=0&filter_ticket_errors=0&filter_barcodes_needed=0&filter_barcodes_not_verified=0&filter_b2b_only=0&filter_ticket_public=0&filter_ticket_held=0&filter_ticket_private=0&filter_ticket_no_qty=0&filter_ticket_also_deleted=0&filter_inhand=0&filter_no_pdfs=0&filter_broker_tickets=0&filter_nonbroker_tickets=0&filter_event_id=" + self.event_id + "&events_view=1&filter_tm=1&sort_col=column_history&sort_dir=desc&iDisplayStart=" + str(idisplaystart) + "&iDisplayLength=1"
        for idisplaystart in range(0, 2500)
    ]
    return payload_variables

    async def fetch_all_listings(self):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    payloads = await self.payload_worker()
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = [self.fetch_listing(payload, client, queue) for payload in payloads]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    while not queue.empty():
        yield await queue.get()
```

Comment: You can't have `return` outside a function definition. Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Where do you use `payload_variables`? Is that `payloads`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding the code you posted, but the basic structure should be something like this:

```
async def fetch_all_listings(self):
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    idisplaystart = 0
    idisplaylength = 50
    while True:
        payload = f"filter_ticket_id=&filter_tmr_ticket_id=&filter_ticket_ext_id=&filter_vendor_id=&filter_ticket_section=&filter_ticket_row=&filter_ticket_seat=&filter_ticket_last_change_from=&filter_ticket_last_change_to=&filter_price_from=&filter_price_to=&filter_cost_from=&filter_cost_to=&filter_qty_from=&filter_qty_to=&filter_tag_id=&filter_consignment=0&filter_non_consignment=0&filter_ticket_errors=0&filter_barcodes_needed=0&filter_barcodes_not_verified=0&filter_b2b_only=0&filter_ticket_public=0&filter_ticket_held=0&filter_ticket_private=0&filter_ticket_no_qty=0&filter_ticket_also_deleted=0&filter_inhand=0&filter_no_pdfs=0&filter_broker_tickets=0&filter_nonbroker_tickets=0&filter_event_id=" + self.event_id + "&events_view=1&filter_tm=1&sort_col=column_history&sort_dir=desc&iDisplayStart={idisplaystart}&iDisplayLength={idisplaylength}"
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            self.fetch_listings(payload, client, queue)
            await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        if queue.empty():
            break
        while not queue.empty():
            yield queue.get()
        idisplaystart += idisplaylength
```

After each fetch, you check whether it returned anything, and stop the loop when that happens. Otherwise, increment the start variable and continue the loop.

It's usually preferable to fetch in batches rather than 1 at a time, I've added the `idisplaylength` variable for that.